# Moment of inertia related question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, integration, approximations, volume

Sorry for the undetailed title, but when the moment of inertia is calculated in a solid cylinder, the volume of a "sheet" of the cylinder is calculated. I've only seen the volume as $$length*thickness*height = 2\pi r*dr*height$$, but I disagree with that. Shouldn't only the inner length of the "sheet" be $2\pi r$ and the outer part $2\pi (r+dr)$? That way the volume would be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we take the volume of the cylinder with radius $r+dr$:

$$ V_\text{outer} = \pi(r+dr)^2h $$

and subtract the volume of the cylinder with radius $r$:

$$ V_\text{inner} = \pi r^2h $$

Then the volume we are left with is the volume of the shell:

$$\begin{align}
 V_\text{shell} &= V_\text{outer} - V_\text{inner} \\
                &= \pi(r+dr)^2h - \pi r^2 h \\
                &= \pi h(2rdr + dr^2) \\
                &= \pi r^2 h\left(2\frac{dr}{r} + \left(\frac{dr}{r}\right)^2\right)
\end{align}$$

But $dr \ll r$ so the fraction $dr/r \ll 1$ and that means that $(dr/r)^2 \ll dr/r$. That means we can approximate the volume of the shell by:

$$  V_\text{shell} \approx 2\pi r h dr $$

because $(dr/r)^2$ is so much smaller than $dr/r$ that it can be ignored. And in the limit of $dr\rightarrow 0$ the approximation becomes exact and we get:

$$  dV= 2\pi r h dr $$

Answer (score 0):

Your visual image is correct, but it doesn't change the volume meaningfully.  Thinking informally, the difference between $2\pi r$ and $2\pi(r+dr)$ is infinitesimally small, and has a vanishingly small effect.  It's similar to how 5 and 5+0.000000000000000000000000001 are nearly the same and become increasingly close to the same as I add more zeros.

In fact, the difference you mention is the [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) between simple Riemann sum integration and trapezoidal integration.  That tiny difference matters when you are approximating the volume of the cylinder with a small number of layers, but becomes vanishingly small when the number of layers approaches infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Since ${\rm d}r \ll r$ it means that $(r + {\rm d}r) = r$

What is the area of the cross section

$$ \pi (r+{\rm d}r)^2 - \pi r^2 = \pi (2 r + {\rm d}r) {\rm d}r = 2 \pi r {\rm d}r $$